# Why dynamic css may not apply immediately

Tags: javascript

NOTE: I could not replicate the issue in jsfiddle or jsbin, so unfortunately I will demonstrate the issue only via screenshots.

In my work project some JavaScript control is not rendering properly.

[image: Bad render]

I found that it renders properly if I wrap the rendering logic in `setTimeout(renderLogicFunction, 30);`. Number `30` was found during experiments. If value is less than 10 it always renders incorrectly. If it is greater than 30 it is always correct. For 10-30 it is pretty random.

[image: Good render]

I started to debug the rendering logic side-by-side and found that one of the columns has wrong width

[image: Bad width]

However in good rendering

[image: Good width]

Inner HTMLs for both of those controls are the same.

Let's see when the `16px` came from

[image: Good CSS]

This refers to the inline style

[image: Inline CSS]

Then I checked that the bad rendering page also has this inline style but for whatever reason it is not applied yet.

If I let debugger go, I can check that the CSS rule was already applied but it's too late as the column width was taken during calculations for rendering and its current width is not being taken into account anymore. The only way to fix it is to trigger control's refresh. But I think it is not elegant at all.

Do you have any ideas why that happens?

Comment: Can you add a link to somewhere where we can see the full source, even if the bug isn't reproducible? There might be something that seems irrelevant to you that could be caught by someone else!

Comment: @IStanley I think I can't to give link to the production system due to NDA. And as I said I could not reproduce the issue with the naive approach. It is probably not useful. See http://jsbin.com/fewojabeza/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: If you're having to delay some aspect of the rendering process then its likely that some asynchronous task is completing too late. What exactly is it that you are delaying with setTimeout? Is it one specific aspect of the table layout or is it everything, classes applied to the columns (i.e., that which sets the 16px width) included?

Answer (score 0):

When you need a style to become inmune to overwrite, and make it able to overwrite previous rules of the very same style, you can add it !important

```
div { width:100%; }
div { width:50%; }
```

Will render your div elements at 50% width, while

```
div { width:100% !important!; }
div { width:50%; }
```

will render your div elements at 100%.

If you use this wisely on your CSS styles you'll probably be able to fix your problem.

Comment: If the problem were to do with style overrides, surely a) the inline style he wants would be overriding everything else and b) it wouldn't vary depending on how long the page takes to render?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using some 3th party library which resizes columns.

Instead of `setTimeout(renderLogicFunction, 30);` it could probably be replaced with jQuery's document ready, https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: In my particular case document.ready won't help because a) it is already called within document.ready; b) it is rendered via partial postback (ancient MS AJAX UpdatePanel)